# VSCode Opening duplicate search results with split screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode with a split screen, so 2 groups of tabs.  Sometimes when I do a search I click a file in the search results and it creates a new tab in one of the groups, even though I already have that file open in the other tab group.  I imagine this is because my cursor focus is in the first group, but I would think it could be smart enough to look though all my open tabs to see if I have that file open already.  Is there a setting for that?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1479607/in-vs-code-with-split-panels-open-reference-in-already-open-file):

"workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true

File > Preferences > Settings > (Workbench > Editor: Reveal If Open)